# Login problem on my Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I can’t log in to my Mac because my wireless keyboard isn’t responding. Mouse is working ok. Green light is flashing on keyboard. Tried changing batteries.

Comment: Have you tried any other USB Keyboard as input?

Comment: Is your wireless keyboard paired with your mac?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in any USB keyboard to make sure the OS is working and then triage and troubleshoot the wireless keyboard.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204621